# Force all axis labels to show

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

In ASP.NET Column Chart, when the chart size is small some axis labels are not shown.

**Question:** How can I force all the label to show even if they have to overlap?

Comment: Can you quickly give a background for the problem

Comment: Hi, I am drawing a column chart using ASP.NET charting. I have 10 points to draw. the width of the chart is 300px. The axis label of some points is not showing due to the lack of space. I was wondering if I can force it to show even if there is not enough space. Thanks. Hope I was clear

Comment: Try setting the `Interval` property to 1, this should force it to show the labels

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. Add it as an answer so I can Accept it.

Comment: To make it more clear `          chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Set the `Interval` property for the Axis to 1, this will enforce it to display all the available labels irrespective of the space limitation.

Comment: Great tip, +1.  For those arriving by Google like me, Interval can be found at `ChartAreaID.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval=1` or at `ChartID.Areas("myChartAreaName").AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval=1`

Comment: or even here...

    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
      <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="myChartAreaName">
          <AxisX Interval="1">
     
          </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>'

Comment: Those coming here looking for a MVC solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703049/set-interval-in-chart-net-mvc3

Comment: This answer has its limitations.  If you interval=1 it will display a label even when no data exists.  i.e. If you have a date range as an x-axis it will interval the dates by 1 day even though the day doesn't exist.

Comment: Another place it can found is `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;` if you have added a chart are using `chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());`

Comment: If this does not work, set the axis major tick mark interval to 1 as well.  See here: "The Interval property of a major tick mark, grid line or label of the axis has priority over the Interval property setting of the Axis object."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EvilDr, your comment helps, after adding '.LabelStyle.' then it works, previously i was just '.AxisY.Internal', which does not do anything without Prefix .LabelStyle.'