# MVC4 Chart / X-Axis Labels Skip Every Other One

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

I am using System.Web.Helpers.Chart, for ONE very simple graph in my MVC application.

The graph being displayed is only showing labels on every other column.

[image: Example of Chart]

The code that creates the chart looks like this:

```
var chart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .DataBindTable(dataSource: chartData, xField: "Province")
            .AddSeries(chartType: "column", axisLabel: "Province")
            .GetBytes("png");

        return chart;
```

The "chartData" comes from a SQL table, and is comprised of two fields
Province CHAR(2)
Shipments INT

I have made the graph much wider, and that did not fix the issue. The graph is embedded into the view using a partial view.

if anyone can help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to provide it a "theme" to set the "interval" to 1. In your case, the code should look something like this:

```
string t = @"<Chart> <ChartAreas> <ChartArea Name=""Default"" _Template_=""All""> <AxisX Interval=""1""></AxisX> </ChartArea> </ChartAreas> </Chart>";

var chart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: t)
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: chartData, xField: "Province")
        .AddSeries(chartType: "column", axisLabel: "Province")
        .GetBytes("png");

return chart;
```

I've kept the "theme" to the bare minimum by only applying the interval, but there are other options obviously.

More:
[set interval in chart .net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703049/set-interval-in-chart-net-mvc3)